# Replace generated meshes with imported meshes in Unity

Tags: unity

I generated a **lot of meshes** for my project, but they have no import settings and I happen to need them. So I exported the objs, deleted the old assets and imported those files (that were exported using OBJexporter), making sure that the names DO match. Issue is, none of my scene objects recognize the new objects.

I could easily undo the harm, but I really need to change those mesh assets to the ones with import settings. How do I do that, so the engine does recognize them?

Comment: Unity matches assets by generated UID, not by name. It's possible to remap your IDs, but if you have a *lot* then this might be a major slog and going back to solve your original problem might be easier/faster.

Comment: I found that out the hard way :/ Thanks for the heads up, well next time I reimport my generated meshes right after generation (they are generated in an editor script, not runtime).

Comment: Out of curiosity, for what reason do you need import settings that can't be done with generated meshes?

Comment: I need to access its vertices, triangles and UVs to create a full copy. I need that copy because for no apparent reason I can't have the same mesh on my `MeshFilter` as well as my `Particle System` 's `Shape` because the game crashes every time on android.

Comment: That seems like an odd bug in Unity. Have you submitted a bug report?

Comment: Also, can you create a copy just by doing `var newMesh = Instantiate(meshFilter.sharedMesh)`?

Comment: Yes I submitted one. I actually found another way for the purpose I needed so I gave this up. I might try that `Instantiate` some time later, thanks for the help. The way I found was loading my meshes to a `Dictionary<string, Mesh>` from Resources where I store everything anyway (that I guess will have to load at some point) and this way the meshes get "re-loaded".